# OnMouseOver this, show this but OnMouseOut, hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="profile-banner" onMouseOver="fadeIn('edit-banner');" onMouseOut="fadeOut('edit-banner');">
    <div id="edit-banner">
        Edit Banner
    </div>
</div>
```

(Formating is being weird on stackoverflow.. so ignore the formating.)

Anywho, the problem I'm having is the second I put my mouse over the "Edit banner" area, it recognizes that i'm on another element, so it fades it out. I need it to stay as long as i'm in that profile-banner area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/evomez/1/edit)**

Use CLASS `.edit-banner`

```
<div class="profile-banner">
    <div class="edit-banner">
        Edit Banner
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.profile-banner').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function( e ){
    var inOut = e.type=='mouseenter' ? 1 : 0;
    $(this).find('.edit-banner').stop().fadeTo(500, inOut);
});
```

Comment: I don't think you'd use `.next`...wouldn't you use `.children` or `.find`?

Comment: @ianpgall sure, I was in hurry and just about to modify the example. Creating a demo

Comment: No problem, I just wasn't sure if I forgot the difference between `.next` and `.find` for a second :)

Comment: :) @ianpgall hahaha no way! it's a *must know*!

Comment: @Jake thanks! glad it was helpful. If you don't understand the *ternary operator* I used ( `? :` ) just make a search for it! It's fun and easy to understand

Comment: Haha I know, I thought I was crazy for a minute there!